# Autowired bean in spring boot test is null

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test

I have a spring boot test defined as followed, and which autowires a service class.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyApplication.class)
class MyApplicationTest {
   @Autowired MyService myService;
}
```

When I start the test, the MyService constructor gets called and the stacktrace shows

```
<init>:112, MyService (com.my.service)
newInvokeSpecial:-1, DirectMethodHandle$Holder (java.lang.invoke)
invokeExact_MT:-1, Invokers$Holder (java.lang.invoke)
invokeImpl:91, DirectConstructorHandleAccessor (jdk.internal.reflect)
newInstance:67, DirectConstructorHandleAccessor (jdk.internal.reflect)
newInstanceWithCaller:499, Constructor (java.lang.reflect)
newInstance:483, Constructor (java.lang.reflect)
instantiateClass:211, BeanUtils (org.springframework.beans)
instantiate:87, SimpleInstantiationStrategy (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
instantiateBean:1326, AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
createBeanInstance:1232, AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
doCreateBean:582, AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
createBean:542, AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
lambda$doGetBean$0:335, AbstractBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
getObject:-1, AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$632/0x0000000800ed9858 (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
getSingleton:234, DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
doGetBean:333, AbstractBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
getBean:208, AbstractBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
preInstantiateSingletons:953, DefaultListableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
finishBeanFactoryInitialization:918, AbstractApplicationContext (org.springframework.context.support)
refresh:583, AbstractApplicationContext (org.springframework.context.support)
refresh:147, ServletWebServerApplicationContext (org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context)
refresh:734, SpringApplication (org.springframework.boot)
refreshContext:408, SpringApplication (org.springframework.boot)
run:308, SpringApplication (org.springframework.boot)
loadContext:132, SpringBootContextLoader (org.springframework.boot.test.context)
loadContextInternal:99, DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate (org.springframework.test.context.cache)
loadContext:124, DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate (org.springframework.test.context.cache)
getApplicationContext:124, DefaultTestContext (org.springframework.test.context.support)
injectDependencies:118, DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener (org.springframework.test.context.support)
prepareTestInstance:83, DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener (org.springframework.test.context.support)
prepareTestInstance:43, SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener (org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure)
prepareTestInstance:248, TestContextManager (org.springframework.test.context)
postProcessTestInstance:138, SpringExtension (org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter)
lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$8:363, ClassBasedTestDescriptor (org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor)
execute:-1, ClassBasedTestDescriptor$$Lambda$470/0x0000000800e3a618 (org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor)
executeAndMaskThrowable:368, ClassBasedTestDescriptor (org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor)
lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$9:363, ClassBasedTestDescriptor (org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor)
accept:-1, ClassBasedTestDescriptor$$Lambda$469/0x0000000800e3a210 (org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor)
accept:-1, StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator$$Lambda$296/0x0000000800c6a770 (java.util.stream)
accept:197, ReferencePipeline$3$1 (java.util.stream)
accept:179, ReferencePipeline$2$1 (java.util.stream)
forEachRemaining:1625, ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator (java.util)
copyInto:509, AbstractPipeline (java.util.stream)
wrapAndCopyInto:499, AbstractPipeline (java.util.stream)
forEachRemaining:310, StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator (java.util.stream)
forEachRemaining:735, Streams$ConcatSpliterator (java.util.stream)
forEachRemaining:734, Streams$ConcatSpliterator (java.util.stream)
forEach:762, ReferencePipeline$Head (java.util.stream)
invokeTestInstancePostProcessors:362, ClassBasedTestDescriptor (org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor)
lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$6:283, ClassBasedTestDescriptor (org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor)
execute:-1, ClassBasedTestDescriptor$$Lambda$468/0x0000000800e3a000 (org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor)
execute:73, ThrowableCollector (org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical)
instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance:282, ClassBasedTestDescriptor (org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor)
lambda$testInstancesProvider$4:272, ClassBasedTestDescriptor (org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor)
get:-1, ClassBasedTestDescriptor$$Lambda$412/0x0000000800d1efd0 (org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor)
orElseGet:364, Optional (java.util)
lambda$testInstancesProvider$5:271, ClassBasedTestDescriptor (org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor)
getTestInstances:-1, ClassBasedTestDescriptor$$Lambda$315/0x0000000800cb0000 (org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor)
getTestInstances:31, TestInstancesProvider (org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution)
lambda$prepare$0:102, TestMethodTestDescriptor (org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor)
execute:-1, TestMethodTestDescriptor$$Lambda$411/0x0000000800d1edc0 (org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor)
execute:73, ThrowableCollector (org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical)
prepare:101, TestMethodTestDescriptor (org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor)
prepare:66, TestMethodTestDescriptor (org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor)
lambda$prepare$2:123, NodeTestTask (org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical)
execute:-1, NodeTestTask$$Lambda$255/0x0000000800c9bb88 (org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical)
execute:73, ThrowableCollector (org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical)
prepare:123, NodeTestTask (org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical)
execute:90, NodeTestTask (org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical)
accept:-1, SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService$$Lambda$270/0x0000000800ca23a0 (org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical)
forEach:1511, ArrayList (java.util)
invokeAll:41, SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService (org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical)
lambda$executeRecursively$6:155, NodeTestTask (org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical)
execute:-1, NodeTestTask$$Lambda$266/0x0000000800ca1900 (org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical)
execute:73, ThrowableCollector (org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical)
lambda$executeRecursively$8:141, NodeTestTask (org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical)
invoke:-1, NodeTestTask$$Lambda$265/0x0000000800ca16f0 (org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical)
around:137, Node (org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical)
lambda$executeRecursively$9:139, NodeTestTask (org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical)
execute:-1, NodeTestTask$$Lambda$264/0x0000000800ca12f8 (org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical)
execute:73, ThrowableCollector (org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical)
executeRecursively:138, NodeTestTask (org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical)
execute:95, NodeTestTask (org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical)
accept:-1, SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService$$Lambda$270/0x0000000800ca23a0 (org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical)
forEach:1511, ArrayList (java.util)
invokeAll:41, SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService (org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical)
lambda$executeRecursively$6:155, NodeTestTask (org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical)
execute:-1, NodeTestTask$$Lambda$266/0x0000000800ca1900 (org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical)
execute:73, ThrowableCollector (org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical)
lambda$executeRecursively$8:141, NodeTestTask (org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical)
invoke:-1, NodeTestTask$$Lambda$265/0x0000000800ca16f0 (org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical)
around:137, Node (org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical)
lambda$executeRecursively$9:139, NodeTestTask (org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical)
execute:-1, NodeTestTask$$Lambda$264/0x0000000800ca12f8 (org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical)
execute:73, ThrowableCollector (org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical)
executeRecursively:138, NodeTestTask (org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical)
execute:95, NodeTestTask (org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical)
submit:35, SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService (org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical)
execute:57, HierarchicalTestExecutor (org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical)
execute:54, HierarchicalTestEngine (org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical)
execute:107, EngineExecutionOrchestrator (org.junit.platform.launcher.core)
execute:88, EngineExecutionOrchestrator (org.junit.platform.launcher.core)
lambda$execute$0:54, EngineExecutionOrchestrator (org.junit.platform.launcher.core)
accept:-1, EngineExecutionOrchestrator$$Lambda$208/0x0000000800c8ecd8 (org.junit.platform.launcher.core)
withInterceptedStreams:67, EngineExecutionOrchestrator (org.junit.platform.launcher.core)
execute:52, EngineExecutionOrchestrator (org.junit.platform.launcher.core)
execute:114, DefaultLauncher (org.junit.platform.launcher.core)
execute:86, DefaultLauncher (org.junit.platform.launcher.core)
execute:86, DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher (org.junit.platform.launcher.core)
execute:53, SessionPerRequestLauncher (org.junit.platform.launcher.core)
startRunnerWithArgs:71, JUnit5IdeaTestRunner (com.intellij.junit5)
execute:38, IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1 (com.intellij.rt.junit)
repeat:11, TestsRepeater (com.intellij.rt.execution.junit)
startRunnerWithArgs:35, IdeaTestRunner$Repeater (com.intellij.rt.junit)
prepareStreamsAndStart:235, JUnitStarter (com.intellij.rt.junit)
main:54, JUnitStarter (com.intellij.rt.junit)
```

After construct, then @PostConstruct got called and when I inspect the fields of MyService, I find all the autowired fields inside this service are non-null.

But when the control comes the the Test code, the Autowired MyService object has a different object id than the one seen above, as seen from the watch window. Also it shows itself as MyService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB, and all of the fields in this class autowired or not, including fields with initializers are null. This shows that this is some mocked class, although I'm not using Mockito in my test. Why is the real class not getting injected, even though it is getting constructed ?

Comment: It is not a mockito mock it is a spring mock, probably because you are using transactions. ALso your test doesn't make sense you are mixing JUnit4 and JUnit5. Please repost your stacktrace with code tags, it is code not a quote (and currently it is toptally unreadable). Finally what is the issue you hnave? Upon invoking the constructor nothing has been injected yet as there is nothing to inject into (the object is still being constructed).

Comment: Done. I meant to say I found the fields non-null during @PostConstruct. I have edited the description now.

Comment: And I ask again your problem is what? It doesn't work? You get nullpointers? Your test fails?

Comment: NPE. \@Autowired MyService myService; is the mocked instance, and the \@Autowired fields (and even initialized fields) I have defined in this class are all null.

Comment: Again it is **not a mocked instance** it is a proxy created by Spring because you enabled some AOP (probably `@Transactional` on the service). The autowired fields cannot be null, only on the proxy (as it doesn't need them). So if they are `null` this is probably because you have final methods or are invoking private or package default methods instead of protected/public methods.

Comment: I'm not using @Transactional in my service. The proxy has all fields null, including fields with compile time initializers. Is there some way to indicate to spring boot test environment, not to use proxies?

Comment: I was setting a default access field from the test. The problem persisted even if I made the field public. However when I introduced a setter public method to use from the test instead, then it worked without NPE. Thanks for the help, I had to read a bit about proxy CGLIB.

Comment: It is about method access. If that is default, private or final cglib cannot create a proxy method for it and will invoke it on the proxy instead of passing it on to the actual method on the actual instance.